# input is not aPCH file ( swift compiler error ) after updated to 8.3 Xcode Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pch, xcode8

I just Updated My Xcode to 8.3 asn Swift 3.1 and got the Error in Running Project Which Says .

[image]

as i already have my pch file on place as it was working well befor in 8.2 of XCODE

Thanks For  Help.

Comment: Does the file exist? Is the content correct? Check that `-enable-bridging-pch` is not set.

Comment: I assume that you already tried Project->Clean  and Project->Clean Build Folder ?

Comment: @Sulthan How to enable That please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this file you are used to bridge OC and Swift，now you should creat a new .h file to